# getting associated values with max sql

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

mysql 5.x
I have this so far that returns each contender, (which is made up of participants who each have individual salaries) and the total salary for the contender. I want to get the row which contains the max salary.

```
SELECT StageName, MAX(TotalSalary)
FROM (
        SELECT StageName, SUM(DailySalary) AS TotalSalary
        FROM CONTENDER, PARTICIPANT
        WHERE idContender = Contender
        GROUP BY idContender
    ) AS AllContenders;
```

This gives me a row with the max salary, but it just gives the name for the first row, not the correct row, which is what i need to find

```
+-------------+-------------+
| StageName   | TotalSalary |
+-------------+-------------+
| Life        |        2600 |
| Death       |        6000 |
| AC/DC       |       16000 |
| Yin         |        2700 |
| Yang        |        3300 |
| Error Group |        1337 |
+-------------+-------------+
```

This is what i get with the middle select statement.

What i get with the full code is life and 16000, 
what im supposed to get is acdc and 16000

Comment: MySQL 5.x or 8.x?

Comment: What happens if you have two (or more) contenders tied up in first place?

Comment: Also, your query returns **random** data since you are not aggregating the column `StageName`. Do you want the max, the min, the average, the mode...?

Comment: That query is invalid... Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: i added more stuff above

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are grouping by `idContender` but selecting `StageName`, which is giving you a random `StageName` for each group of `idContender` instead of stopping you with an error (MySql-only issue). So instead of selecting `StageName, SUM(DailySalary)` in your subquery, you need to select `idContender, SUM(DailySalary)`. Finally you can change your subquery to a joined query with `CONTENDER` and using `order by` and `limit` you can select the first record with the highest `TotalSalary`:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.TotalSalary as MaxSalary
FROM CONTENDER t1 join (
        SELECT idContender, SUM(DailySalary) AS TotalSalary
        FROM CONTENDER, PARTICIPANT
        WHERE idContender = Contender
        GROUP BY idContender
    ) AS t2
on t1.id = t2.idContender
order by MaxSalary desc
limit 1
```